# Как удалить пробелы и буквы с input

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как удалить все пробелы и буквы на лету с input с помощью чистого js.

Comment: У input'a есть тип number

Comment: у input есть атрибут pattern

Answer (score 1):

Повесьте слушатель события 'input' и делайте replace значения. Думаю есть лучше способ, но вроде и этот не плох.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('input', (e) =>
{
  e.target.value = e.target.value.replaceAll(/[A-Za-zА-Яа-я ]+/g, '')
});
```

```html
<input>
```

Comment: такой вариант не подходит, так как при ctr+c или автоподстановке проходит и буквы и пробелы

Comment: Отредактировал.